# Dropdown menu with textbox in angular5

Tags: angular5

I am new to angular 5. I need a help to add dropdown menu, when I select the contents in dropdown the search box should be displayed.

This is text box code.I need to put this in dropdown so that when I'll select A i need to get search text box for A. When i select module same text box should be displayed for module.

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <label for="A">A:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="A" [(ngModel)]="A" class="form-control" id="A">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchA()">search</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <label for="module">MODULE:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" name="module" [(ngModel)]="module" class="form-control" id="module">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchModule()">search</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Instead of two search text boxes, I want use dropdown to display single search textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short example of accomplishing it. (i ignored bootstrap for brevity)

It was possible, by declaring my dropdown value as a variable called "searchOption" and then using it as a condition for every search button.

```
Select
<select [(ngModel)]="searchOption">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="module">module</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchA()" *ngIf="searchOption == 'A'">searchA</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchModule()" *ngIf="searchOption == 'module'">searchModule</button>
```